# Changing the font document

Tags: fonts, texstudio

I need to write a whole document with a specific font. My problem is that when I compile it seems to be working, but my pdf result has the original font. Nothing happened.

I have downloaded my .ttf font [here](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/roboto), and I have installed it into my fonts folder in Windows 7 using drag and drop.

Then I have been using Xelatex compiler to compile this code :

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass[a4paper]{letter}
\usepackage{xltxtra,fontspec,xunicode}
\setsansfont{Roboto-Regular}

\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{Letter}

\address{Address}

\opening{Dear Mr}

Some text here

\closing{\mbox{}}

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Any ideas? Do you think I missed something here?

Comment: `\setmainfont`, not `\setsansfont`. Avoid `xltxtra` and `xunicode`: `fontspec` is sufficient.

Comment: Thank you. So now I'll need to make all the compilation by going into "Tools"->"Compilation"->"Xelatex" ? Is there a way to do it faster?

Comment: It depends on what front-end you're using: is it TeXStudio?

Comment: I notice that with this method I can not use \textbf{} anymore to get my text into bold. Is that normal ?

Comment: @egreg, yes it is TeXStudio

Comment: For boldface you have to download also the corresponding bold font.

Comment: Found it ! It worked well.

Comment: @egreg hey, I have some difficulties on another question, du you have any ideas how I can figure out to do that ? http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/172600/48977

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I installed the whole font family in my system folder and then modified your example into

```
% !TeX program = xelatex
% !TeX encoding = utf8

\documentclass[a4paper]{letter}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Roboto}

\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{Letter}

\address{Address}

\opening{Dear Mr}

Some text here also \textbf{boldface}

\closing{\mbox{}}

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With the first two lines in the shown format, just pressing the “Build & View” button will choose XeLaTeX as the engine. The two “magic lines” you had are good for TeXShop, a Mac OS X only application.

Comment: Nice ! This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you

Comment: Just to add something, I've modify my font into : `\setmainfont[BoldFont=Roboto-Bold_0.ttf]{Roboto-Regular.ttf}`

Comment: @FlorentP It's always difficult to say when Windows is involved, at least for me, because I know nothing about it.

Comment: hey, I have some difficulties on another question, du you have any ideas how I can figure out to do that ? http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/172600/48977